# Write Xaml Textblock in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I am using this code to write a Textblock to a Xaml page:

```
  Sale.Name = "Price";
  Sale.Text = "$200";
  deatilLayout.Children.Add(Sale);
  Grid.SetRow(Sale, 1);
```

This successfully places the data on the xaml page, but not in the right place.

```
  <FlipView
            x:Name="flipView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsFlipView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Item Details"
            TabIndex="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}">

            <FlipView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="FlipViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,137,0,70"/>
                </Style>
            </FlipView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <!--
                        UserControl chosen as the templated item because it supports visual state management
                        Loaded/unloaded events explicitly subscribe to view state updates from the page
                    -->
                    <UserControl Loaded="StartLayoutUpdates" Unloaded="StopLayoutUpdates">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollViewerStyle}" Grid.Row="1">

                            <!-- Content is allowed to flow across as many columns as needed -->
                            <common:RichTextColumns x:Name="richTextColumns" Margin="117,0,117,47">
                                <RichTextBlock x:Name="richTextBlock" Width="560" Style="{StaticResource ItemRichTextStyle}" IsTextSelectionEnabled="False">

                                    <Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight" Margin="0,0,0,180">
                                        <InlineUIContainer>
                                            <Image x:Name="image" MaxHeight="480" Margin="0,20,0,100" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding Image}" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                                        </InlineUIContainer>
                                    </Paragraph>
                                    <Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,30" LineHeight="65" FontFamily="Global User Interface">
                                        <Run FontSize="52"  FontWeight="Thin" Text="{Binding Title}" />

                                    </Paragraph>
                                    <Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,50">
                                        <Run Text="TT $" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Thin"/>
                                        <Run FontSize="30" FontWeight="Normal" Text="{Binding Subtitle}"/>


                                    </Paragraph>
                                    <Paragraph x:Name="price" x:FieldModifier="public" />
                                    <Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,40">

                                        <Run FontSize="27" FontWeight="Normal" Text="{Binding Weight}"/>

                                    </Paragraph>
                                    <Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,40" LineHeight="40">

                                        <Run FontSize="35" FontWeight="Normal" Text="{Binding Description}"/>

                                    </Paragraph>
                                    <Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,40" LineHeight="30">

                                        <!--<Run FontSize="22" FontWeight="SemiLight" Text="{Binding Category}"/>-->
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </RichTextBlock>

                                <!-- Additional columns are created from this template -->
                                <common:RichTextColumns.ColumnTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <RichTextBlockOverflow Width="560" Margin="30,0,0,0">
                                            <RichTextBlockOverflow.RenderTransform>
                                                <TranslateTransform X="-1" Y="4"/>
                                            </RichTextBlockOverflow.RenderTransform>
                                        </RichTextBlockOverflow>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </common:RichTextColumns.ColumnTemplate>
                            </common:RichTextColumns>

                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                                <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state inside the FlipView -->
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

                                    <!-- Respect the narrower 100-pixel margin convention for portrait -->
                                    <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="richTextColumns" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="97,0,87,57"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MaxHeight">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="400"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

                                    <!-- When snapped, the content is reformatted and scrolls vertically -->
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="richTextColumns" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="17,0,17,57"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="scrollViewer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollViewerStyle}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="richTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="280"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MaxHeight">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="160"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </UserControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        </FlipView>
```

I would like to place the data in the paragraph in the `RichTextBlock`, which is in the `Grid` "detailLayout".

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

One way you do it is, in your XAML file, change your Paragraph element to the following:

```
<Paragraph x:Name="price" />
```

This makes the Paragraph instance visible to the code-behind as a field by the name of "price". Then, as an example, you may access and set the contents this Paragraph instancein the code-behind using the following code:

```
string textToSet = "Price: $200"; // Replace this value with whatever value you want to 
                                  // set in the paragraph.
Run textRun = new Run();
textRun.Text = textToSet;    
this.price.Inlines.Add(textRun);
```

Then, if you want to clear the contents of the Paragraph instance, you can do the following in the code-behind:

```
this.price.Inlines.Clear();
```

By default, when assigning a name to an element in the XAML page, that element is not publicly visible to external code. If it is necessary to access the 'price' Paragraph element from outside of the XAML page's code-behind, you will need to change the Paragraph element's declaration to the following:

```
<Paragraph x:Name="price" x:FieldModifier="public" />
```

One last thing to note is that you can't access named elements if they are within a DataTemplate (commonly used with WPF items controls). So if this is the case, you might want to go with an MVVM approach.

Comment: Code doesn't recognize `price`

Comment: I've made edits to further clarify what needs to be done to make the 'price' element accessible from outside the scope of your XAML page. Though I am unsure if this will fix your problem as I haven't seen where your C# code is located scope-wise relative to your XAML page.

Comment: I still get the error `Error 1 'BG.ItemDetailPage' does not contain a definition for 'price' and no extension method 'price' accepting a first argument of type 'BG.ItemDetailPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
` The C# is the file for the Xaml Page. This Xaml Page is ItemDetailPage.xaml and the file with the C# code is ItemDetailPage.xaml.cs

Comment: Are you positive that ItemDetailPage.xaml has an element like the following:

`<Paragraph x:Name="price" />`

Comment: I'm afraid without seeing a more complete view of the code in question I am going to be unable to diagnose your issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, but now that you have updated your code, its apparent that my solution won't work for you. Please see my edited post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you place Grid.Column="" and Grid.Row=""

```
<Paragraph Grid.Column="0" and Grid.Row="0">
</Paragraph>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to use MVVM and try this:

```
 <RichTextBlock    FontSize="12"    FontFamily="Segoe UI" >
                                <Paragraph >
                                    <Run Text="{Binding Sale.Text}"/> <Run Text="{Binding Sale.Text }"/>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </RichTextBlock>
```

If you are not using MVVM you will have to créate a "Run" object, insert the text, and add it  to the chilrends of the RichTextBlock.